# How do I assign the return value of a case statement to the cell to the right of the current cell in a For loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, select-case

## Background

In VBA, you can assign the return value of a Select Case statement to [specific cells](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/select-case.html) as shown below:

> 3. Add the Select Case structure.
>
>    `Select Case score
>         Case Is >= 80
>             result = "very good"
>         Case Is >= 70
>             result = "good"
>         Case Is >= 60
>             result = "sufficient"
>         Case Else
>             result = "insufficient"
>      End Select`
>
> Explanation: Excel VBA uses the value of the variable score to test
>   each subsequent Case statement to see if the code under the Case
>   statement should be executed.
>
> 4. Write the value of the variable result to cell B1.
>
> `Range("B1").Value = result`

This is straightforward to me, however, I am trying to loop through a column of cells to do the same thing with a [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/8981474).  The code above does this for one instance.  However, I want to do this for each cell and categorize the result in the cell to the right.

## Attempted solution

Below is the code I used so far:

```
....variables defined at the beginning as strings
Set MyRange = Sheet6.Range("A2:A355")
For each cell In MyRange
    Select Case cell.Value
        Case Is = raid
            result = "area"
        Case Is = fifty
            result = "one"
        ... more cases ad nauseum
    End Select
Next
```

You can assign a specific cell with the range method approach above.  But I want to assign the resulting string one cell to the right (i.e., in column B but the same row). Hence my question...

## Question

How do I specify that I want the result of a case statement to be output once cell to the right of the current cell within a For loop in VBA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need:

```
cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result
```

following your `End Select`